# unable to format string in PHP using custom function

Tags: php, string, function

```
<?php
$string = 'tHis is aN unEVen string that needs to be formated properly';

// custom function created combining multiple functions
function varform($var){
   ucwords(strtolower(htlmentities(trim($var))));
   return $var;
}

$string = varform($string);
echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please use the formatting tools provided to format your question. I've cleaned it up for you this time.

Comment: htlmentities is htmlentities you did a typo mistake

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the result of all your manipulations to the variable you are about to  return

```
<?php
$string = 'tHis is aN unEVen string that needs to be formated properly';

// custom function created combining multiple functions
function varform($var){
   // assign change to the variable
   $var = ucwords(strtolower(htmlentities(trim($var))));
   return $var;
}

$string = varform($string);
echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: @johnP - Thanks, I've fixed that as well now

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your code

```
function varform($var){
   ucwords(strtolower(htlmentities(trim($var))));
------------------------^ //It's htmlentities() not htlmentities()
   return $var; //you're just returning the value that is passed to the method
}
```

You need to get the return value from the PHP methods and return that from your function

```
function varform($var){
   $var = ucwords(strtolower(htmlentities(trim($var))));
   return $var;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) replace htlmentities by htmlentities

and as the previous commenters said

```
function varform($var){
  return ucwords(strtolower(htmlentities(trim($var))));
}
```